# Removing Stop Phrases from DocumentTermMatrix

Tags: r, n-gram, topic-modeling, corpus, stop-words

Below, I do a basic topic modeling for the "crude" data. I know I can remove stop words using tm_map, but I can't figure out how to do so **after** the bigram tokenization occurs.

```
library(topicmodels)
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

data("crude")
words <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
words <- tm_map(words, removePunctuation)
words <- tm_map(words, stripWhitespace)

BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 2))

#bigram tokenization
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(words,control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
ui = unique(dtm$i) 
dtm = dtm[ui,] #remove "empty" tweets

lda <- LDA(dtm, k = 2,control = list(seed = 7272))

topics <- tidy(lda, matrix = "beta")

##Graphs
top_terms <- topics %>%
  group_by(topic) %>%
  top_n(10, beta) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(topic, -beta)

top_terms %>%
  mutate(term = reorder(term, beta)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(term, beta, fill = factor(topic))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()

#single
stopwords1<- stopwords("english") ##I actually use a custom list: read.csv("stopwords.txt", header = FALSE)
adnlstopwords1<-c("ny","new","york","yorks","state","nyc","nys")

#doubles
stopwords2<-levels(interaction(stopwords1,stopwords1,sep=' '))
adnlstopwords2<-c(stopwords2,c("new york", "york state", "in ny", "in new",
                  "new yorks"))

stopwords<-c(stopwords,adnlstopwords1,stopwords2,adnlstopwords2)
```

My question is how to remove these bigrams from the dtm and not using tm_map or what work-around there might be. Note that the "new york" based bigrams might not occur in the crude data, but are important to my other data.

Comment: To be more clear, I'd like to do it after building the bigrams because I want to include bigrams like "I care" but eliminate bigrams like "I don't." This is why just removing single words can't get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this solution from the "gofastR" package in R:

```
dtm2 <- remove_stopwords(dtm, stopwords = stopwords)
```

However, I still saw stop phrases in the results. After reviewing the documentation, remove_stopwords assumes it has a sorted list -- you can prep your stopwords/phrases using the prep_stopwords() function from the same package.

```
stopwords<-prep_stopwords(stopwords)
dtm2 <- remove_stopwords(dtm, stopwords = stopwords)
```

In order to do this **and** stem. We can perform the stemming in the tm_map part of the code and remove the stepwords as follows:

```
stopwords<-prep_stopwords(stemDocument(stopwords))
dtm2 <- remove_stopwords(dtm, stopwords = stopwords)
```

as this will stem the stopwords which will then match the already stemmed words in the dtm.